# Is it possible to pull data from specific places in multiple workbooks and paste it in specific places in a single sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to pull data from thousands of Excel workbooks with changing file names. The goal is for the macro to run through every workbook in my folder and pull specific data and paste it in a single sheet.

I know a loop is necessary for this to work. So far, this is what I have but it isn't executing correctly. The macro runs but nothing happens. **Can someone help me troubleshoot this?**

```
Sub WBsInFolderToMaster()

Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

On Error Resume Next

Dim X As Long
    For X = 6 To 8
        If Sheet2.Cells(X, "E").Value2 <> "" Then
   
            Dim FPath As Long
            FPath = Sheet2.Cells(X, "F").Value
       
            Dim openwb1 As Workbook
            Set openwb1 = Workbooks.Open(FPath, UpdateLinks:=False)
       
            Dim SPtab As Worksheet
            Set SPtab = openwb1.Sheets("SUMMARY PAGE")

            Dim PItab As Worksheet
            Set PItab = openwb1.Sheets("PROJECT INFORMATION")

            Dim CDtab As Worksheet
            Set CDtab = openwb1.Sheets("COST_DETAIL")

            Dim CStab As Worksheet
            Set CStab = openwb1.Sheets("COST_SUMMARY")
               
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------
            'SUMMARY PAGE TAB

            'Unprotect workbook
            openwb1.Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"
           
            'Unprotect sheet
            SPtab.Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"

            'Copy and Paste Disaster
            SPtab.Range("C8").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "G").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste PW
            SPtab.Range("E7").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "H").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste Applicant
            SPtab.Range("C3").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "I").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste Program
            SPtab.Range("C7").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "J").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste RFR
            SPtab.Range("E8").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "K").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
           
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------
            'PROJECT INFORMATION TAB
           
            'Unprotect sheet
            PItab.Unprotect Password:="Password"

            'Copy and Paste Disaster
            PItab.Range("C8").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "L").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste PW
            PItab.Range("E7").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "M").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
           
            'Copy and Paste Applicant
            PItab.Range("C3").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "N").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste Program
            PItab.Range("C7").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "O").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste RFR
            PItab.Range("E8").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "P").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
   
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------
            'COST_DETAIL TAB
           
            'Unprotect sheet
            CDtab.Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"

            'Copy and Paste SUBRECIPIENT
            CDtab.Range("D2").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "Q").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste ELIGIBLE AMOUNT
            CDtab.Range("O5").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "R").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste SUBSTANTIATED AMOUNT
            CDtab.Range("X6").Copy = Sheet2.Range(X, "S").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
           
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------
            'COST SUMMARY TAB
           
            'Unprotect sheet
            CStab.Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"

            'Copy and Paste SUBRECIPIENT
            CStab.Range("C2").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "T").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

            'Copy and Paste SUBSTANTIATED AMOUNT
            CStab.Range("X6").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "U").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
           
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------
            'CLOSING WORKBOOK

            openwb1.Close (False)
        End If
    Next X

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
'WHEN LOOP IS COMPLETE

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `On Error Resume Next`. That is just hiding all the errors.
2. `Dim FPath As Long` should be `Dim FPath As String`.
3. You can't `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` in one line. It has to be two separate steps, *but*...
4. It would be much better to avoid the clipboard here by using value transfer, e.g.:

```vb
SPtab.Range("C8").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "G").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
...
SPtab.Range("E7").Copy = Sheet2.Cells(X, "H").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
...
```

become

```vb
Sheet2.Cells(X, "G").Value = SPtab.Range("C8").Value
...
Sheet2.Cells(X, "H").Value = SPtab.Range("E7").Value
...
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you! Updated but it still is not working. I think the issue revolves around `Dim FPath` but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Should be a `String` instead of a `Long`.